# How can I also log complete git pull history?

Tags: git, logging, git-pull, gitblit

I am using gitblit to host git repository in my organisation. I have to log all the git pull operations also on all the repositories by any user for the purpose of tracking the history. How can I do that ?

Comment: You would probably have to check the server logs, this isn't an operation that is of interest to anyone, usually. Might I ask what kind of problem you're hoping to solve by monitoring when your developers pull from the repository? Seems like an odd operation to survey.

Comment: You can't. If I run `git pull` on my system, all *your* system sees is my `git fetch` step. You have no idea whether I ran `git merge` or `git rebase` after my `git fetch`.

Comment: The repositories are developed by various developers at different locations and I have to track who all downloaded their repositories, as part of making the developers aware of how many people have actually pulled/downloaded their code/repository and also I can track how many people at any point of time have the repository with them.